# Left Join Specific Row

Tags: mysql, sql

Think this is probably fairly simple but cannot find the correct search terms, so if this is duplicated then great cause im sure there will be an answer somewhere.

I have the following tables setup

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned auto_increment NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `billing_run` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned auto_increment NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned auto_increment NOT NULL,
  `billing_run_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (billing_run_id) REFERENCES billing_run(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with the following data

```
insert into customer (name) values ('test customer');
insert into billing_run (date) values ('2019-01-01 12:00:00');
insert into billing_run (date) values ('2019-02-01 12:00:00');
insert into billing_run (date) values ('2019-03-01 12:00:00');
insert into invoice (customer_id,billing_run_id) values (1,1);
```

SQLFiddle here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a54162/5

And i want to get the `customer` records that do not have an `invoice` related to `billing_run` with `id` of 2

My query

```
select c.id from customer c
left join invoice i on i.customer_id = c.id
left join billing_run br on br.id = i.billing_run_id and br.id = 2
where i.id is null
```

returns 0 records. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you join the table `customer` (1 row) with the table `invoice` (1 row).
This join will return 1 row because there is a match between the columns in the `ON` clause:

```
on i.customer_id = c.id
```

(both `i.customer_id` and `c.id` have the value `1` in your sample data).
So there is not any row with `i.id is null`.
 
The next join to the table `billing_run` does not affect the first 2 joined tables.
So the condition:

```
where i.id is null
```

returns no rows. 
The correct condition (which you had in the original fiddle) is:

```
where br.id is null
```

because the join to the table `billing_run` will return a non matching row for the condition:

```
on br.id = i.billing_run_id and br.id = 2
```

because there is no `i.billing_run_id  = 2` in `invoice`.

Comment: But if i create invoice entries for all billing runs i still get data back -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c419d/1

Comment: Of course you do. These are the 2 rows that do not have a match in table `billing_run`. This is what you get if you remove the where clause: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/foP9ky8PiX62PWMR5jXJE8/1. There are 3 rows as expected. When you set the condition `where br.id is null` 1 row is removed.

Comment: So how can i get only the invoices missing from a specific billing run ?

Comment: If what you mean is get billing runs that do not have a corresponding invoice: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/foP9ky8PiX62PWMR5jXJE8/3. If you want to check for a specific billing run: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/foP9ky8PiX62PWMR5jXJE8/4

Comment: The billing runs are created first, then i want to be able to create invoices for each customers for each billing run. Customers may be added after the invoices are created. So i want to find missing invoices for a customer.

Comment: This is what you should have mentioned right from the start. In this case you can use NOT EXISTS and not a join: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/foP9ky8PiX62PWMR5jXJE8/6 I added a customer which is returned because there is no invoice for him with `billing_run_id = 2`. Fir this code you don't need the table `billing_run` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do an exclusive where clause this will return the 1 row that you want.

```
select * from customer c 
where c.id not in (Select customer_id from invoice i LEFT JOIN billing_run br on 
i.billing_run_id=br.id WHERE br.id=2 and br.id is not null)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a54162/14

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `billing_run` table.  So I think you intend:

```
select c.id
from customer c left join
     invoice i
     on i.customer_id = c.id and i.billing_run_id = 2
where i.id is null
```